# Files in python

Tags: python, file

My program has to do two things with this file.
It needs to print the following information:

Comment: First of all, what is the issue you're having? Second of all, you should put your try.except around the lines where the exception can be thrown. not around the definition of your function. Also, you should consider having a look at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. Also have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (Never tried this one though)

Comment: It's not so much an issue with the program but not knowing what to do. I want my output to look like the one displayed above and I don't know how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getlines(somefile):
    f = open(somefile).readlines()
    lines = [line for line in f if not line.startswith("#") and not line.strip() == ""]
    return lines

entries = getlines(input("Name of input file: "))
animal_visits = {}
month_visits = [0] * 13

for entry in entries:
    # count visits for each animal
    animal = entry[:3]
    animal_visits[animal] = animal_visits.get(animal, 0) + 1

    # count visits for each month
    month = int(entry[4:6])
    month_visits[month] += 1

print("Total Number of visits for each animal")
for x in sorted(animal_visits):
    print(x, "\t", animal_visits[x])

print("====================================================")
print("Month with highest number of visits to the stations")
print(month_visits.index(max(month_visits)))
```

Outputs:

```
Name of input file: log
Total Number of visits for each animal
a01      3
a02      3
a03      8
====================================================
Month with highest number of visits to the stations
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I prepared the following script:

```
from datetime import datetime # to parse your string as a date                                      
from collections import defaultdict # to accumulate frequencies                                     
import calendar # to get the names of the months                                                    

# Store the names of the months                                                                     
MONTHS = [item for item in calendar.month_name]                                                     

def entries(filename):                                                                              
    """Yields triplets (animal, date, station) contained in                                         
    `filename`.                                                                                     

    """                                                                                             
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp:                                                                
        for line in (_line.strip() for _line in fp):                                                
            # skip comments                                                                         
            if line.startswith("#"):                                                                
                continue                                                                            
            try:                                                                                    
                # obtain the entry or try next line                                                 
                animal, datestr, station = line.split(":")                                          
            except ValueError:                                                                      
                continue                                                                            
            # convert date string to actual datetime object                                         
            date = datetime.strptime(datestr, "%m-%d-%Y")                                           
            # yield the value                                                                       
            yield animal, date, station                                                             

def visits_per_animal(data):                                                                        
    """Count of visits per station sorted by animal."""                                             
    # create a dictionary whose value is implicitly created to an                                   
    # integer=0                                                                                     
    counter = defaultdict(int)                                                                      
    for animal, date, station in data:                                                              
        counter[animal] += 1                                                                        
    # print the outcome                                                                             
    print "Visits Per Animal"                                                                       
    for animal in sorted(counter.keys()):                                                           
        print "{0}: {1}".format(animal, counter[animal])                                            

def month_of_highest_frequency(data):                                                               
    """Calulates the month with the highest frequency."""                                           
    # same as above: a dictionary implicitly creation integer=0 for a                               
    # new key                                                                                       
    counter = defaultdict(int)                                                                      
    for animal, date, station in data:                                                              
        counter[date.month] += 1                                                                    
    # select the (key, value) where value is maximum                                                
    month_max, visits_max = max(counter.iteritems(), key=lambda t: t[1])                            
    # pretty-print                                                                                  
    print "{0} has the most visits ({1})".format(MONTHS[month_max], visits_max)                     

def main(filename):                                                                                 
    """main program: get data, and apply functions"""                                               
    data = [entry for entry in entries(filename)]                                                   
    visits_per_animal(data)                                                                         
    month_of_highest_frequency(data)                                                                


if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                          
    import sys                                                                                      
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Use as:

```
$ python animalvisits.py animalvisits.txt
Visits Per Animal
a01: 3
a02: 3
a03: 8
January has the most visits (3)
```

**Having done that** I must advice you agains this approach. Querying data like this is very inefficient, difficult, and error prone. I recommend you store your data in an actual database (Python offers an excellent binding for SQlite), and use SQL to make your reductions.

If you adopt the SQlite philosophy, you will simply store your queries as plain text files and run them on demand (via Python, or GUI, or command line).

Visit http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html for more details.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using regex?
I guess your code would reduce to a very few lines if you use regex?
use findall("DIFFERENT REGULAR EXPRESSIONS") and store the values into list. Then you can count the length of the list.

Comment: It is really unnecessary in that case. A split(':') would do the job. Try avoiding `regex` as much as possible

Comment: Can you just give me an example to how split(':') works? And for which section am I applying this to?

Comment: @lfhfsfhjsf, take a look here http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html. Also, if you are interested, I posted the source code for string operations (but is from python 1.5!): http://randomgalaxy.com/tools/loadpy.php?script=/stackoverflow/files-in-python/string.py

Comment: @crazycode regular expressions are seldom a good idea. They have a very specific use case, and splitting a string at a well-defined separator is most definitively NOT one of them. I recommend you visit the Python docs, and familiarize yourself with `strip`, `split`, `find`, and `replace` (all `basestring` methods), which can often accomplish may tasks that Regular Expressions could accomplish too. However, the methods do so in a much simpler manner.